# Reading SQL query arguments from external csv file

Tags: sql, csv, where-clause

I have following SQL query:

```
select * from P_SPC_LOT L,P_SPC_CHART_POINT CP
where L.spcs_id = CP.spcs_id and 
(L.route like 'FL%' or L.route like 'RE%' or L.route like 'FE%') and
L.operation in ('123','234','456') and
L.data_collection_time > current_date -7 and rownum <100000
```

I am interesting to read L.operation values from external .csv file with "Operation" column. How that can be done? In addition, if reading from external file will slow query? I don't have DBA write privileges so looking for temporary csv table usage as not part of DB.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Thank you for putting my attention. Just started to learn SQL, but this issue doesn't resolve my problem to read arguments from external csv file.

Comment: You can't join on an external file very well in most cases.  If this is a MSSQL question, you can add a 'linked table' to SQL, but that probably requires more privileges than you have; you'll need your DBA to do that part.  You're going to need an additional table in the database otherwise.  Regardless, rd_nielsen is right, below, when it comes to adding a table and using that.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Answer (score 1):

Import the CSV file into a table, and use it as follows (assuming the CSV file is loaded into a table named `ops` with a column named `operations`):

```
select * 
from 
    P_SPC_LOT L
    inner join P_SPC_CHART_POINT CP on L.spcs_id = CP.spcs_id 
where 
    (L.route like 'FL%' or L.route like 'RE%' or L.route like 'FE%') 
    and L.operation in (select operation from ops) 
    and L.data_collection_time > current_date -7 
    and rownum <100000;
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please add code how to load ops?

Comment: How you import a CSV file depends on what DBMS you're using and what client application or programming language you're using.

Comment: I am using ToAD for SQL queries and Python as programming language. Csv file is external file and not part of DB

Comment: The Toad client will connect to several DBMSs, and I don't use Toad so don't know if or how it differs for different DBMSs, but a simple Google search turns up this, which may be useful to you: https://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle/w/toad_for_oracle_wiki/151.i-have-a-flat-file-csv-tab-delimited-etc-and-i-want-to-import-the-data-to-a-table-what-is-the-best-way-to-do-that-using-toad

Comment: Most DBMSs also have scripting tools that will allow you to import the CSV programmatically.  If you want to use Python, you will have to install the Python library for the DBMS you are using, create a database connection, then you can use Python's `csv` library to read the CSV file and insert the data into an `ops` table.